# Flexbox height in React Native

Tags: react-native, flexbox, react-native-flexbox

I'm trying to create a simple content-sized dialog box in React Native.  Highest in this hierarchy I have my overlay `<View>` styled so:

```
 {
   position: 'absolute',
   top: 0,
   left: 0,
   width: '100%',
   height: '100%',
   zIndex: 100,
   backgroundColor: COLOR
}
```

Within this, I have a wrapper `<View>` with this style:

```
{
   flex: 1,
   alignItems: 'center',
   justifyContent: 'center'
}
```

Then I have the dialog `<View>`:

```
{
   flex: 1,
   width: '86%',
   maxWidth: 450,
   flexDirection: 'column',
   justifyContent: 'flex-start',
   alignItems: 'flex-start',
   backgroundColor: 'white',
   borderWidth: 5,
   borderColor: 'gold'
}
```

It looks like the problem, though, lies in the way I'm building the dialog:

```
<View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'flex-start', alignItems: 'flex-start'}}>
  <Image source={require('../../assets/icons/warning.png')} 
   style={{resizeMode: 'contain', height: 50, width: 48, marginRight: 30}} />
  <View style={[flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'flex-start', alignItems: 'flex-start']}>
    <Text>{this.props.dialogMessage}</Text>
    <View style={{flex: 1, width: '100%', flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'flex-start'}}>
       <Button dismissOverlay={this.props.dismissOverlay} />
    </View>
  </View>
</View>
```

With this styling I get this result:

[image: Huge dialog]

If I change `flex` to 0, I get this instead:

[image: Clipped dialog]

How can I get the dialog to size to the content?

Comment: Did you tried `left: 0, right: 0, top: 0, bottom: 0` on top view

Comment: Try using react-native-modal

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Dialog `<View>` don't set `flex` at all. Have it like this

```
{
   width: '86%',
   maxWidth: 450,
   flexDirection: 'column',
   justifyContent: 'flex-start',
   alignItems: 'flex-start',
   backgroundColor: 'white',
   borderWidth: 5,
   borderColor: 'gold'
}
```

If it does not work, could you provide more code on the content inside of your Dialog `view`?

Comment: I think you're right in suspecting the problem lies with the views within the dialog.  If I replace them with a simple `<Text>` run, the dialog sizes correctly.  I'll edit my question to include the inner views.

Comment: I applied your solution to the dialog subviews, removing the flex property, and it worked!  Thank you!

Comment: The key is removing the flex property from both the top ```<View>``` and the immediate sub ```<View>```